# *ALL Authority in iNavigator

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I use iNavigator for data extraction and my team consists of 20 analysts with individual user id's. The analysts save their final data tables in a common library, down load the data and send it to the users. Issue is that analysts are unable to down load tables created by others (i.e. I'm unable to down load a table created by my colleague when he's on leave). Is there a sql command which can be given while creating the tables in iNavigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using long SQL names on your tables instead of short system names.  That being the case, the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm) says:

> **Table authority:** If SQL names are used, tables are created with the
>   system authority of *EXCLUDE to *PUBLIC. If system names are used,
>   tables are created with the authority to *PUBLIC as determined by the
>   create authority (CRTAUT) parameter of the schema. If the owner of the
>   table is a member of a group profile (GRPPRF keyword) and group
>   authority is specified (GRPAUT keyword), that group profile will also
>   have authority to the table.

So you can either remember to grant authorities to other developers after creating the table or as mentioned above; you can make all your developers members of the same group (GRPPRF) and have their profiles default (CRTAUT) to group ownership of newly created objects.